# Which version(s) of WiX integrate with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

The documentation on the various WiX sites ([Sourceforge](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or [Codeplex](http://wix.codeplex.com/)) is a little unclear. Is it the case that only version 3.5 (still in beta) of WiX will integrate with Visual Studio 2010 (i.e. allow me to add and edit a WiX project in a solution)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.5.

You'll want to subscribe to the [Wix users list at sourceforge](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/wix-users) and the [3.5 release RSS feed.](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/wix3.5.feed)

Use the Extension Manager in Visual Studio to download 3.5 and integrate it with VS, then update your binaries from the latest release.

Unfortunately, the latest releases don't follow the folder structure that the extension lays down, so you'll have to update everything by hand.  This is pretty typical of Wix, sorry to say.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Extension Manager authoring. Use the WiX installers instead -- they're correct.